# Waiting For Debugger on Android using NetBeans

Tags: android, debugging, netbeans, freeze

When I try to debug an Android app with NetBeans and the nbandroid plugin, it starts the emulator, and eventually when the emulator comes up it says

> **Waiting For Debugger**
>   Application [app name] ([package name]) is waiting for the debugger to attach.

and I get a Force Close button.

Here is the log from DDMS.

```
01-14 11:44:46.131: INFO/ActivityManager(85): Force stopping package [packagename] uid=-1
01-14 11:44:46.131: INFO/ActivityManager(85): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=[packagename]/.[activityclassname] }
01-14 11:44:46.311: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(420): Shutting down VM
01-14 11:44:46.331: DEBUG/jdwp(420): adbd disconnected
01-14 11:44:46.371: INFO/AndroidRuntime(420): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
01-14 11:44:46.411: INFO/ActivityManager(85): Start proc [packagename] for activity [packagename]/.[activityclassname]: pid=427 uid=10032 gids={3003}
01-14 11:44:47.200: WARN/ActivityThread(427): Application [packagename] is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-14 11:44:47.231: INFO/System.out(427): Sending WAIT chunk
01-14 11:44:50.280: DEBUG/SntpClient(85): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-14 11:44:56.253: WARN/ActivityManager(85): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
01-14 11:44:57.003: WARN/ActivityManager(85): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43f85578 [packagename]/.[activityclassname]}
01-14 11:45:05.350: DEBUG/dalvikvm(166): GC_EXPLICIT freed 595 objects / 29656 bytes in 120ms
01-14 11:45:10.320: DEBUG/dalvikvm(228): GC_EXPLICIT freed 190 objects / 13056 bytes in 92ms
01-14 11:45:15.331: DEBUG/dalvikvm(304): GC_EXPLICIT freed 277 objects / 13112 bytes in 92ms
01-14 11:45:20.401: DEBUG/dalvikvm(162): GC_EXPLICIT freed 586 objects / 32240 bytes in 109ms
01-14 11:47:05.161: DEBUG/dalvikvm(162): GC_EXPLICIT freed 49 objects / 2704 bytes in 93ms
01-14 11:49:05.201: DEBUG/dalvikvm(162): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15 objects / 600 bytes in 130ms
01-14 11:49:47.595: INFO/jdwp(85): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.710: INFO/jdwp(155): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.740: INFO/jdwp(160): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.750: INFO/jdwp(162): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.772: INFO/jdwp(166): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.810: INFO/jdwp(194): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.820: INFO/jdwp(224): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.861: INFO/jdwp(228): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.872: INFO/jdwp(242): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.880: INFO/jdwp(271): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.980: INFO/jdwp(427): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.980: INFO/jdwp(304): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:47.980: INFO/jdwp(337): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:48.020: INFO/jdwp(293): Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
01-14 11:49:50.290: DEBUG/SntpClient(85): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
01-14 11:50:10.970: DEBUG/Email(271): *** synchronizeMailboxGeneric ***
01-14 11:50:11.250: DEBUG/dalvikvm(271): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9369 objects / 455104 bytes in 126ms
01-14 11:51:05.171: DEBUG/dalvikvm(162): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15 objects / 600 bytes in 90ms
01-14 11:53:05.180: DEBUG/dalvikvm(162): GC_EXPLICIT freed 15 objects / 600 bytes in 95ms
01-14 11:54:50.293: DEBUG/SntpClient(85): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Here is the NetBeans ant log

```
init:
deps-jar:
Compiling 1 source file to C:\[apppath]\build\classes
compile:
Updating zip: C:\[apppath]\dist\[appname].apk_

THIS TOOL IS DEPRECATED. See --help for more information.

Deleting: C:\[appdir]\dist\[appname].apk_
Deleting: C:\[apppath]\dist\[appname].apk__
Building zip: C:\[apppath].zip
jar:
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/[appname].apk
Success
569 KB/s (275945 bytes in 0.473s)
About to start [packagename]/[packagename].[activityclassname]
Starting: Intent { cmp=[packagenamel]/.[activityclassname] }
```

NetBeans tells me the process is still running and gives me a stop button to 'kill' if I want.

Also my CPU and disk are mostly idle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well.  You have to manually attach the debugger while the emulator says "Waiting for debugger to attach".  In Netbean's menu bar, click "Debug", then "Attach Debugger...".  You have to select your package from the "Process" drop down list, and then click "Attach".  That should do it.

This works in Netbeans 7 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices: connect a debugger, or kill the process.

Looking at your logcat, you have at least two different desktop applications that are trying to connect to each application process, which is where the "Ignoring second debugger" messages are coming from.

This would happen if you were, say, running Eclipse with the ADT plugin, and the stand-alone DDMS at the same time.  I don't know what you're running or what the netbeans plugin does, but I would start by figuring out if you have two different things fighting for control.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that Eclipse was running at the same time messed up the attaching of the debugger. Closing Eclipse, and it all went as expected =)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have turned on debugging for your app on emulator.

Comment: How do I do that? I think it is on but we might not be talking about the same thing.

Comment: I mean: menu > `Dev Tools` > `Development Settings`. Choose your app, and select `Wait for debugger`, Maybe this will help.